# Cache for reducing time of expensive object creations?

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, pool

I have to use a legacy library that is in some parts very expensive on object creation (just "plain" objects, no database connection or likewise).
As I'm writing a webservice with it, there will be many threads targeting the library.

The main problem will be the garbage collector having to clean up all the heavy objects of every thread.

Now I came around several cache pool approaches. But I have no experience in this.
Could you recommend what cache pool library is most suitable if object creation is very expensive?

- Guava
- Apache Commons
- or own implementation?

Comment: What version of Java are you working in?  It makes a big difference.  The "legacy" library doesn't really matter, unless it's using its own pooling.

Comment: JDK 7, in general always with the newest version. The legacy does not have own pooling mechanisms.

Comment: Have you actually profiled your application and know for sure the object construction/GC is the bottleneck? Modern JVMs handle multiple `new` pretty well.

Comment: “the garbage collector having to clean up all the heavy objects” is nonsense. The garbage collector does not depend on the objects that are actually garbage. It processes the objects that are still alive only. So caching means keeping more objects alive and hence raise the work for the garbage collector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object creation isn't what it used to be -- it is much more efficient.  In most cases with modern JVMs, you are better off not worrying about it.  Don't introduce the complexity and maintenance overhead of creating your own caching code unless you are *sure* you really need to -- and you can't be sure until you get some performance metrics via testing.